# How can I store an emitted value from a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

From a child component, I am emitting a value that I want the parent to receive. In the parent component, I have a property that I have initiated to null, and the aim is to change this value once the parent receives the emitted value but for some reason it doesnt work.

here is the code

the child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="gameComponent">
    <b-row>
        <b-col>
            <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>     
    <b-row>
        <b-col>
            <p>{{ game.platform }}</p>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
        <b-col>
            <b-button @click="viewGameFromLibrary(game)">View Game</b-button>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
            <b-button @click="removeGameFromLibrary(game.id)">Remove Game</b-button>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import api from '../assets/javascript/api.js'
import ViewGameVue from './ViewGame.vue';

export default {
    props:['game'],
    methods:{
        removeGameFromLibrary(id){
            api.removeGameFromLibrary(id);
            location.reload();
        },

        viewGameFromLibrary(game){
            this.$emit("viewGame", game)
        }

    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

this is the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="library">
    <ViewGame />
      <b-row>
        <b-col v-for="game in games" lg="4" xl="4">
            <GameInLibrary v-bind:game="game"  @viewGame="getGame"/>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import api from '../assets/javascript/api.js'
import GameInLibrary from '@/components/GameInLibrary'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      games:[],
      gameToView:''

    }
  },
  methods: {
    getGame(game){
      this.gameToView = game
    }
  },
  components:{
    GameInLibrary,
    ViewGame: ()=> import('./ViewGame')
  },
  created(){
    api.getAllGamesFromLibrary(this.games)
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

this.gameToView = game doesn't seem to work, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Run  `console.log(game)` inside `getGame` method. What value do you see?

Comment: @AlexHoffman I see the following: {…} , this object is expandable in the console and when I expand it I can see the data corresponding to the data I am trying to send.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ran `console.log(game)` inside `getGame()` and it displayed the expected value, it means that emitted `game` value is not undefined and it actually being assigned to `this.gameToView`, so what's the problem?

So your parent component receives the emitted value `game` from one child component.

If you then need to send this value from the parent to another child component: `<ViewGame/>` you just need to pass it like this:

#### Parent component:

```
<div class="library">
  <ViewGame :gameToView="gameToView"/>
  ...
</div>
```

#### Child component `ViewGame`:

```
<div>{{gameToView}}</div>
...
props: ['gameToView']
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to prop down this value to the ViewGame child component. I  can't do that unless I get access to this value.

Comment: I can see the object which is very weird... it seems to be very random. It works fine and I can see the object in the Vue console. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work it's very inconsistent. There seems to be no explanation as to why that is.

Comment: @Christopher I updated the answer, since you mentioned you need to send this value to a 3rd component

Comment: update, your solution works now for some reason. If anything comes up I will comment here.